# Get candlestick data in PineScript v5 when on a different chart type?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a script and its code is simple:

```
theHigh = high
theLow = low
theOpen = open
theClose = close

[PDH,PDL,PDO,PDC] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, “D”, [theHigh[1], theLow[1], theOpen[1], theClose[1]])
```

However, if I change my chart type to, let’s say, renko, then PD levels are incorrect.

Is there any way I can calculate the data based off and only off candlesticks no matter what the chart type is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new ticker id with `ticker.standard` and then pass it to the `security()` function. This way it would always get data from the standard candlestick chart.

> **ticker.standard**
> Creates a ticker to request data from a standard chart that is unaffected > by modifiers like extended session, dividend
> adjustment, currency conversion, and the calculations of non-standard
> chart types: Heikin Ashi, Renko, etc. Among other things, this makes
> it possible to retrieve standard chart values when the script is
> running on a non-standard chart.
>
> ***ticker.standard(symbol) → simple string***

---

```
tick_standard = ticker.standard(syminfo.tickerid)
[PDH,PDL,PDO,PDC] = request.security(tick_standard, “D”, [theHigh[1], theLow[1], theOpen[1], theClose[1]])
```

For the non-standard charts you can read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Non-standard_charts_data.html?highlight=ticker%20standard#non-standard-charts-data).